# To pick a colleague up

Tags: word-usage

can I say to my colleague " ...turn left,  go straight for a minute , then you can text me and I'll PICK YOU UP"

I am at the office, so I'll get out of the office to meet her and show the way, we will go to my office together

Comment: Text me and I will come get you.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular context, it sounds a little odd to me. Typically, you use a *vehicle* to pick someone up

> - 2 : to take (passengers or freight) into a vehicle
>     ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pickup))
> - phrasal verb
>     When you pick up someone or something that is waiting to be collected, you go to the place where they are and take them away, often in a car.
>     *She was going over to her parents' house to pick up some clean clothes for Oskar.*
>     ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pick-up))

If you were *driving* to meet your colleague, the person got in, then you drove to your destination, then I would say perfect. But in this case, I would probably phrase it differently. I assume you are walking there. As a commenter suggests, "I'll **come get you**" is fine since it's more broad and includes walking. Also, "walk", as in "I'll *walk* you there":

> [walk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walk) transitive verb
>   4 a : to accompany on foot : walk with walked her home
>   (M-W)

Answer (score -2):

"I'll meet you there."

To pick up has another meaning: If you pick up someone you do not know, you talk to them and try to start a sexual relationship with them.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pick-up

Comment: I almost upvoted but for the added definition of *to pick someone up*, it's not wrong but if someone said they would **pick me up at the airport**, I wouldn't think they were hitting on me :), I'd think they were giving me **a lift**.

Comment: @Owain *I will meet you there* does not include the part where person A brings person B back into their office. It is not conclusive.